# What is the limit of this sequence $x_0 = 1$, $x_1 = 2$, $x_{n + 2} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot (x_n + x_{n + 1})$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I have an exercise in my last assignment for calculus, where basically we have to find the limit of a sequence. We don't know the closed form, so it's quite complicated. We have *maxima*, but it does not tell us the closed form of a sequence.

Basically the sequence is the following:

$$x_0 = 1 \\ \\
x_1 = 2 \\ \\
x_{n + 2} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot (x_n + x_{n + 1})$$

We have find in *Wolfram Alpha* the closed form: $$\frac{1}{3}\cdot 2^{−n}\cdot \left(4 \cdot (−1)^n+5\cdot 2^n\right)$$.

We have then found with maxima that the limit is $$\frac{5}{3}$$. Is this correct?

I would like not to use Wolfram Alpha, and I noticed that this sequence is similar to the *Fibonacci* sequence, where basically the current number is the sum of the previous number. Is there a relation between Fibonacci numbers and this numbers?

How could you obtain the closed formula of this sequence to find the limit? Or is there another easier way?

Comment: You mean sequence not a series.

Comment: Would be really cool if there is a solution for arbitrary initial conditions.

Answer (score 2):

There is a general method for that type of recurrence: look for solutions of the form $x_n=r^n$. Substituting in the equation we get
$$
r^{n+2}=\frac12\,(r^n+r^{n+1})\implies2\,r^2-r-1=0\implies r=1,-\frac12.
$$
The solution is then (using the fact that the equation is linear)
$$
x_n=A\cdot1^n+B\cdot\Bigl(-\frac12\Bigr)^n=A+B\,(-1)^n2^{-n}.
$$
You compute $A$ and $B$ from the values of $x_0$ and $x_1$.

Answer (score 2):

> $$x_{n + 2} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot (x_n + x_{n + 1})$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} x_{n+1} \\ x_{n} \end{bmatrix} = 
\underbrace{
  \begin{bmatrix} \frac 12 & \frac 12 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
}_M
\begin{bmatrix} x_{n} \\ x_{n-1} \end{bmatrix}$$

Since $M$ has eigenvalues of $1$ and $-\frac 12$, then $M^\infty$ converges. To find the limit:

$$\begin{bmatrix} x_{\infty+1} \\ x_{\infty} \end{bmatrix} = 
\underbrace{
  \begin{bmatrix} \frac 23 & \frac 13 \\ \frac23 & \frac13 \end{bmatrix}
}_{M^\infty}
\begin{bmatrix} x_{1} \\ x_{0} \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} \frac 53 \\ \frac 53 \end{bmatrix}$$